# Appium stops in between while running automation on android phone

Tags: appium

i am running automation on android . appium version is 1.4 . It stops/ hangs in between and do not start untill one presses enter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to use the latest version appium-1.5.3 (up to now)
2. Try to use the console Version appium-1.6.3 (up to now)

Comment: can you know any reason why appium behaves like that.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. After upgrading the appium version to 1.5.3, it is resolved.